# custom entry for HashMap / Map

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

Everybody is familiar with the class concept of Java. Each class is able to hold attributes. I want this attributes to be dynamic, which means I want to build a Map that holds variablename->value entries.

Therefore, my idea is to customize the Map interface (use AbstractMap or HashMap) to create a custom ClassAttributesMap. This map should provide a method like "attributesMap.put(new CustomEntry());". Typically Map implementations like HashMap provide a put method, but it is "put(Object key, Object value);".

I solved it for me. Thanks a lot for your hints!

Here is the code that meets my requirements:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    DynAttClass dynClass = new DynAttClass();
    dynClass.keyset();
}

public class DynAttClass {

    private HashMap<DynAttributes, Object> attributesMap = new HashMap();

    public DynAttClass() {
        attributesMap.put(DynAttributes.var1, "value1");
        attributesMap.put(DynAttributes.var2, new Integer());
        attributesMap.put(DynAttributes.var3, new CustomObject());
    }

     //you can delegate the HashMap methods here, for example:
     public Set<DynAttributes> keySet() {
         return attributesMap.keySet();
     }

}

public enum DynAttributes {
    var1, var2, var3;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: _"Here is my code, that isn't working"_ - in what way? Did you debug your code?

Comment: Why do you need a custom map implementation? what is wrong with `HashMap<String,Object>`?

Comment: What exactly does not work? Please post exception traces, test cases, examples. You should make it easy to help you ;-)

Comment: Please tell us at what spot you get which error.

Comment: Have you considered [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You suggest using a CustomEntry, so I'm assuming there is a reason you can't simply use `Map.put`.

If that `Map.put(CustomEntry e)` method is all you need, you could simply create a new class that extends HashMap and add that method to it which is an adapter to the regular `put(key, val)`

Comment: Subclassing a standard Java container is no good idea under almost all circumstances. You (and the OP) were better off using [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)!